# Deserializing an object without a default constructor out of MongoDb + C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, bson

Consider the two classes:

```
public class Entity
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public E2 e = new E2(ConfigClass.SomeStaticMethod());
}

public class E2
{
    [BsonIgnore]
    public int counter = 5;
    public DateTime last_update { get; set; }

    public E2(int c)
    {
        counter = c;
    }
}
```

I'll store and then retrieve an object of type `Entity` to / from a MongoDb like this (assuming collection is empty):

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<Entity>("temp");
collection.Save<Entity>(new Entity());
var list = collection.FindAs<Entity>(new QueryDocument());
var ent = list.Single();
```

Regardless of what `ConfigClass.SomeStaticMethod()` returns, the `counter` field will be zero (the default value for integers). But if I add a default constructor to the `E2` class then `counter` will be `5`.

This means that MongoDb's C# driver has got a problem with calling non-default constructors (which is totally understandable). I know there's a `BsonDefaultValue` attribute defined within BSON library but it can only accept `constant expressions`.

What I'm trying to do is to load the default value of a field out of config files while the rest of object is retrieved from MongoDb!? And of course with the least effort.

**[UPDATE]**

I've also tested this with the same results:

```
public class Entity
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public E2 e = new E2();
    public Entity()
    {
        e.counter = ConfigClass.SomeStaticMethod();
    }
}

public class E2
{
    [BsonIgnore]
    public int counter = 5;
    public DateTime last_update { get; set; }
}
```

Running this code results in `counter` to be zero again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to accomplish it like this:

```
public class Entity
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public E2 e = new E2();
}

public class E2 : ISupportInitialize
{
    [BsonIgnore]
    public int counter = 5;
    public DateTime last_update { get; set; }

    public void BeginInit()
    {
    }

    public void EndInit()
    {
        counter = ConfigClass.SomeStaticMethod();
    }
}
```

The [`ISupportInitialize`](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/#implementing-isupportinitialize) interface comes with two methods of `BeginInit` and `EndInit` which are called before and after the process of deserialization. They are the best places to set default values.